# Adding a formatted table of function properties to a plot

Tags: plotting

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := 2 Sin[2 x + \[Pi]/6]
Print[Style["Function:"  f[x]]]
Print[Style["Domain："]]
xr = 0 <= x <= \[Pi]/2
Print[Style["Zero points of f[x]："]]
sol1 = Solve[f[x] == 0 && xr, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
Print[Style["Intersection point f[x] and the x-axis："]]
zps1 = {x, 0} /. sol1
Print[Style["f'[x] Function："]]
D[f[x], x] // FullSimplify // Factor
Print[Style["Zero points of f'[x]："]]
sol = Solve[D[f[x], x] == 0 && xr, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
Print[Style["Intersection point f'[x]："]]
zps = {x, 0} /. sol
Print[Style["The increasing interval of f[x]："]]
Reduce[D[f[x], x] > 0 && xr, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
Print[Style["The decreasing interval of f[x]："]]
Reduce[D[f[x], x] < 0 && xr, x, Reals] // FullSimplify
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 5 \[Pi]/8}, Automatic}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6], Automatic}]
```

In the above code, the content displayed by the command Print needs to be displayed in the form of a list,

The Target format for table As Follows:

[image]

How to make the content containing the corresponding print of the function display separately in the form of the above list,

and also be able to be displayed in the corresponding area of the function image? Similar to the image below

[image]

All in all,The best form is similar to the following image, with the table fixed to the right of the image. No matter how long the content in the table changes, the table and image are separated into two parts, and they do not affect each other. They can be displayed completely, regardless of how the function changes

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using `Inset`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := 2 Sin[2 x + π/6]
fdom = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
fp = FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]
fz = Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals] /. C[1] -> 1
drv = D[f[x], x]
fdz = Solve[drv == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 1
grid = Transpose[{{"Function", "Domain", "Period", "Zeros", 
      "Derivative", "Stationary\nPoints"}
     , {f[x], fdom, fp, fz, drv, fdz}}] // 
   Grid[#, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {{8, 20}, 3}] &;

Plot[f[x]
 , {x, 0, π}
 , ImageSize -> 600
 , Epilog -> {
   Inset[grid, {π, 2}, {Right, Top}, 1.25, Background -> Yellow]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Similarly:

```
Inset[grid, {0, 2}, {Left, Top}, 1.25, Background -> Yellow]
```

can be used to position the `grid` at the top left corner.

---

**Previously:** (this suffers from resolution problems, so the answer has been updated above.

As an example:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := 2 Sin[2 x + π/6]
fdom = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
fp = FunctionPeriod[f[x], x]
fz = Solve[f[x] == 0, x, Reals] /. C[1] -> 1
drv = D[f[x], x]
fdz = Solve[drv == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 1
grid = Transpose[{{"Function", "Domain", "Period", "Zeros", 
      "Derivative", "Stationary\nPoints"}
     , {f[x], fdom, fp, fz, drv, fdz}}] // 
   Grid[#, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> {{6, 14}, 3}] &;

Plot[f[x]
 , {x, 0, π}
 , ImageSize -> 400
 , Epilog -> {
   Text[Rasterize[grid
     , ImageResolution -> 400
     , RasterSize -> 400], {2.2, 0.90}]
   }
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: How can I set the position of the table to be adaptive to the top left or top right side of the function image?

Comment: @csn899, please see update.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it is a good idea to put the table inside the plot. Why not just use a Grid?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### code (CODE cell, not input cell)

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_]:=2 Sin[2 x+π/6];
xr=0<=x<=π/2;
sol1 = Solve[f[x] == 0 && xr, x, Reals] // FullSimplify;
zps1={x,0}/. sol1;
sol=Solve[D[f[x],x]==0&&xr,x,Reals]//FullSimplify;
zps={x,0}/. sol;

p1= Grid[{   {Style["Function:" ] ,f[x]},
             {Style["Domain："],xr},
             {Style["Zero points of f[x]"],sol1},
             {Style["Intersection point f[x]"],zps1},
             {Style["f'[x] Function"],D[f[x],x]//FullSimplify//Factor},
             {Style["Zero points of f'[x]"],sol},
             {Style["Intersection point f'[x]"],zps},
             {Style["The increasing interval of f[x]"],Reduce[D[f[x],x]>0&&xr,x,Reals]//FullSimplify},
             {Style["The decreasing interval of f[x]"],Reduce[D[f[x],x]<0&&xr,x,Reals]//FullSimplify}},
    Frame->All];
p2=Plot[f[x],{x,0,π/2},
     PlotRange->{{-1/2,5 π/8},Automatic},
     Ticks->{Range[-π,2 π,π/6],Automatic},ImageSize->300]
Grid[{{p2,p1}}]
```